# How to convert a text string to hex string?

Tags: ios, string, hex

Lets say I have a text string :
"Say Hello to My Little Friend"

A function should return hex value as:

5361792048656c6c6f20746f204d79204c6974746c6520467269656e64

Comment: is correct what the error u faced..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't able to write in swift, but in Objective-C below code is may be what you are looking for:

```
    NSString * str = @"Say Hello to My Little Friend";

    NSString * hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                         [NSData dataWithBytes:[str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                        length:strlen([str cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])]];

    for(NSString * toRemove in [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"<", @">", @" ", nil])
        hexString = [hexString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:toRemove withString:@""];

    NSLog(@"hexStr:%@", hexString);
```

Above code gives exact string as you given:

`5361792048656c6c6f20746f204d79204c6974746c6520467269656e64`

Hope it will help:)

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4, Swift 3**

`let hex: String = "ABC".unicodeScalars.filter { $0.isASCII }
                                       .map { String(format: "%X", $0.value) }
                                       .joined()
print(hex) // correctly yields 414243`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this like,

```
NSString *str = @"Say Hello to My Little Friend";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"data %@",data);
```

Optput : `data <53617920 48656c6c 6f20746f 204d7920 4c697474 6c652046 7269656e 64>`

**Swift:**

```
 let string = "Say Hello to My Little Friend"
 let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

**Swift 3:**

```
 let string = "Say Hello to My Little Friend"
 let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```