# How can I print the content of a variable of type Data using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

All I am looking to do is take a string and get its hex value. I've been following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720475/how-to-convert-a-text-string-to-hex-string-in-swift). Here is the code I have in my playground:

```
let str = "Say Hello to My Little Friend"
let data = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)
print("\(data!)")
```

However, my code just prints:

> "60 bytes\n"

How can I print the hex value? For reference, it should be:

```
5361792048656c6c6f20746f204d79204c6974746c6520467269656e64
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just

```
print(data! as NSData)
```

PS: Your expected *hex* is .utf8

Answer (score 58):

Since `Data` is a Sequence of UInt8, you could map each byte to a string and then join them:

```
data.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
```

Comment: I like this better than the accepted answer because it gives the programmer complete control of the output format.

Comment: var dataMap = data.map { String(format: "%02x", $0)}.joined();


print("\(dataMap)")