# Convert Text String into Hex code

Tags: swift, string, hex, des

I am trying to implement DES algorithm in Swift. And to do that, I need to convert my text string, ex. "Hello, world" into Hex string. I've found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720475/how-to-convert-a-text-string-to-hex-string-in-swift) about this way

```
var text = "Hello, world!"
let data = text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)
data?.base64EncodedString()
```

But `base64EncodeString()` obviously does not return what I need. What should I do to get something like

```
48656c6c6f2c20776f726c6421
```

Comment: And you probably want the `.utf8` encoding, not `.utf16`.